# file system associated with /var?

Tags: filesystem

while reading about linux,I got the following:

The `/var` directory may be put in its `own filesystem` so that growth of the files can be accommodated and the file sizes do not fatally affect the system.

when I tried to find out the `file system` for `/var` by `$ df - Th` ,I got..

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5      ext4      141G   19G  116G  14% /
none           tmpfs     4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev           devtmpfs  1.5G  4.0K  1.5G   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     294M  1.2M  293M   1% /run
none           tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs     1.5G   38M  1.4G   3% /run/shm
none           tmpfs     100M   60K  100M   1% /run/user
```

here I am not getting `/var` on `mounted on attribute`, so what type of `file system` is associated with `/var` exactly? how do I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting your question:

> The /var directory **may be** put in its own filesystem...

(Emphasis mine.) They key phrase here is *may be*. It's not uncommon to do so. But the default Ubuntu installation settings don't do so, so you don't have `/var` on a separate partition.

---

There are many scenarios where `/var` belongs on a different filesystem (or even a different disk):

1. You have an application that does a lot of logging. In this case you'd want to protect root (`/`) from becoming full.
2. You're using an SSD for `/` and have an application that makes a lot of read/writes to `/var`. In this case you'd want it on a normal HDD.
3. You're using an application that is I/O intensive (using both storage space and a lot of read/writes), such as a mail server. In this case you'd want `/var` on a RAID array.

And so on... Also see: [Why put things other than /home to a separate partition?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/685/why-put-things-other-than-home-to-a-separate-partition)

Comment: thanx @muru ,,I got it? ,,what are the scenarios where I have to do this(mount /var on a separate partition)..

Comment: @jazzz have a look at the update.

Comment: MySQL is the prime example: the database is stored in /var.

Answer (score 0):

Your /var is just a directory under root (/), so it's ext4 in your case.

Comment: Thanx @ubfan,, but it is written here its own file system in my post,,what does that means..because it is using ext4 here,,(which is for root(/))...

Comment: The quote in your post says that it *may* be written into its own file system, not that it *is*.  By default, Ubuntu will put `/var` into the `/` partition